# Returning multiple lines from a text file in python

Tags: python, return, text-files

I had a function which I wanted to read a file and return multiple values from it though I'm having trouble understanding how this would work. For example if my text file look like this:

```
John 2543
Jack 2453
Henry 3672
Jane 2405 
Terry 9863
```

And my code like this:

```
def function(): 

    file = open('file.txt')    

    for lines in file:
        name, number = lines.split(' ')
        return name

def main():
    print(function())

main()
```

This only returns a name from one line where as I want the entire first column. I understand that if I did a print function instead of return one that would work. However, in this scenario I would like to return the values so that I can use them in conjunction with my other functions. Thank you.

EDIT:

I also had a follow up question as to how I would print the two columns side by side while dedicating a function to each column. So normally, when I print one column after another it would appear as:

```
John 
Jack 
Henry 
Jane 
Terry 
2543
2453
3672
2405 
9863
```

when I want them to appear as:

```
John 2543
Jack 2453
Henry 3672
Jane 2405 
Terry 9863
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a solution with a generator. `yield`ing every line of your file may come in handy if your file is large. that prevents that the whole file has to be read into memory.

the contents of the file are then handled in a `for` loop.

also note the `with` statement to open the file. this takes care of closing it (even if the program crashes) and is the pythonic way to read from a file.

```
def function():

    with open('file.txt') as file:

       for line in file:
           name, value = line.split()
           value = int(value)
           yield name, value

# here you can do what you need to for all the data in the file
for name, value in function():
    print(name, value)
```

i took the liberty to cast `value` to an `int`. do not know if that is useful to you...

if you need to change row/column, then you have to read all to memory and you could to this:

```
data = [(names, values) for names, values in function()]
names = [item[0] for item in data]
values = [item[1] for item in data]
```

you could then pretty-print that with:

```
separator = '|'
name_lst = ['{:6s}'.format(name) for name in names]
value_lst = ['{:<6d}'.format(value) for value in values]

# join the lists to str
print(separator.join(name_lst))
print(separator.join(value_lst))

# John  |Jack  |Henry |Jane  |Terry 
# 2543  |2453  |3672  |2405  |9863
```

Comment: Hi, what if I had to return the other column through a separate function?

Comment: @DrMoe you mean the one i call `value`? you could use the very same function and just `yield value`.

Comment: But if I do that wouldn't the second list just print after the other? What if wanted to print them side by side?

Comment: i don't understand. could you give a mini-example what you would like to do with the first 2 lines?

Comment: I guess it's not really seen as well in this example. But basically I have multiple functions that all each have a long list/column of data. What I want to do is print them so they are all side by side sort of like a table. The problem is that when I do try to print them it ends up going one after another instead of side by side.

Comment: not sure if i understood correctly. tried something (please try to give an example of your desired output in the question; that makes it easier for people to answer).

Comment: I gave an example above

Answer (score 0):

When you return a value the function ends and control returns immediately to the function that called it. So when you return inside the loop, you never execute the loop more than once before the function exits and hands its return value to the calling function.

You need to build the entire list first, and *then* return it.

```
def function():
    with open('file.txt') as file:
        names = []
        for line in file:
            names.append(line.split()[0])

    return names
```

or

```
def function():
    with open('file.txt') as file:
        return [line.split()[0] for line in file]
```

and use it like this:

```
def main():
    for name in function():
        print(name)
```

Comment: I see. So then to pass it through the main function I'd have to iterate over the list to print it in the column format,right?

Comment: What if I wanted to do it for both columns however and keep them both on the same lines? If I do it like the way shown above wouldn't the second column come after the first? This is if let's say hypothetically I had to use a second function to return the second column